# Where to download and how to install JAX-WS wsimport tools?

Tags: java, soap-client, wsimport

Can somebody tell me where to download and how to install JAX-WS `wsimport` tools? I need to download it and install it.

Actually I want to consume SOAP webservices in my code, and I need JAX-WS wsimport tool for that. My google search has not helped me much.

Comment: This question is not "off-topic", it is not asking for a recommendation.  wsimport is a command line utility installed with Java JDK and can be found in the default Java installation directory, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\wsimport.   However, you may need to manually add this path to your System's Environment Variables.

Comment: This question is even more relevant now that JDK 11 does not bundle the tool with the JDK.

Comment: https://javaee.github.io/metro/download unzip, then in `metro/bin/wsimport.bat|sh`

Answer (score 19):

It is shipped with the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) since version 6.

Comment: Not anymore since JDK11

Comment: what alternative options are available if using Java 11?

Comment: You need to use the MetroJS bundle for JDK 11 and up

Comment: Is it possible that you confused "MetroJS" with "Metro - Webservice toolkit" ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984802/installing-metro-jax-ws-issue