# Installing metro-jax-ws and running wsimport issue

Tags: java, soap, java-11, wsimport

Since `wsimport` is not included since JDK11 ([Where to download and how to install JAX-WS wsimport tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966595/where-to-download-and-how-to-install-jax-ws-wsimport-tools)), I think I need to install `metro-jax-ws`; however, there are no instructions on how to do so...

Comment: It is generally adviced to use a build system like maven, which has excellent plugin support for generating WSDL to Java (`jaxws-maven-plugin` or `maven-jaxb2-plugin`). This means no more manual `wsimport` calls on every WSDL change, reducing possible developer error and the need for specialized tools. See for example the "post JDK8" part on https://www.baeldung.com/jax-ws#1-generating-web-service-source-files-from-wsdl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download and unzip the latest release from [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/releases/tag/3.0.2).
2. Install [maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).
3. cd to `metro-jax-ws-3.0.2/jaxws-ri/bundles` and run `mvn install`.
4. After `mvn install`, read the last line of the installation process and find where `jaxws-ri` was installed (e.g., `.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/`).
5. cd to where `jaxws-ri` was installed and then also cd to `{latest_version}/jaxws-ri/bin`.
6. Run `wsimport.sh` (e.g., `sh wsimport.sh http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso\?WSDL`)

Comment: Thanks for these tips, Jack, but there's still no `wsimport` for me, alas.

Under Debian bookworm (now "testing"), I attempted to build Virtualbox from source, a process that requires, among many other things, `wsimport`.  I followed your instructions but I broke down on `mvn install`:: 
    `[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.ws:project:zip:resources:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Debian Bookworm (which is, as of this writing, at the "Debian testing" pre-release phase), and you need `wsimport`, install the package `jaxws`, which will automagically install many dependencies if you haven't already installed them.  Somewhere in all that is the `wsimport` command.  Thereafter, it worked for me, anyway, and I finally succeeded in building VirtualBox from source.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72984803/3545527

5.1. Unzip .m2\repository\com\sun\xml\ws\jaxws-ri\3.0.2\jaxws-ri-3.0.2.zip\

5.2 Add the full path to the unzipped
jaxws-ri/bin  to path before attempting point 6.

For example, on my machine, I added the following to path
.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\ws\jaxws-ri\3.0.2\jaxws-ri-3.0.2\jaxws-ri\bin\